# XAML How to handle errors/failure with a "Save and Close" button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm coming recently from the winforms world and learning how to implement in WPF/MVVM.

I want to implement a SaveAndClose button in XAML. I have a window, Customer, which shows a customer record with a Save, Save and Close, and Cancel button. Cancel is handled in the code behind which simply consists of a `this.Close()`. The form is opened modally and the ViewModel has an EditMode associated with it (Add/Edit/Delete) so that the form can behave differently dependant on the EditMode.

Currently I have:

Within View/Customer.xaml:

```
...
            <Button x:Name="cmdSaveAndClose" 
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                    Width="100" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Margin="2" 
                    Content="Save and Close" 
                    Command="{Binding CommandSaveAndClose}"
                    />
...
```

Within ViewModels/vmCustomer.cs:

```
public ICommand CommandSave
{
    get
    {
        Console.WriteLine("vm.Customer.CommandSave.get");
        if (_updateCustomer == null) _updateCustomer = new RelayCommand(param => UpdateCustomer(), param => CanUpdateCustomer());
        return _updateCustomer;
    }
}

bool CanUpdateCustomer()
{
    return true;
}

void UpdateCustomer()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"vmCustomer.UpdateCustomer _editMode={_editMode}");
    switch (_editMode)
    {
        case enumEditMode.Add:
            if (!_mCustomer.Insert(true)) throw new Exception("Could not insert customer record.");
            _editMode = enumEditMode.Edit; // because it already exists
            break;

        case enumEditMode.Edit:
            if (!_mCustomer.Update(true)) throw new Exception("Could not update customer record.");
            break;

        case enumEditMode.Delete:
            if (!_mCustomer.Delete(true)) throw new Exception("Could not delete customer record.");
            break;

    }
}
```

Two issues:

1. Having come from winforms, what I would normally do is return a `boolean` from `UpdateCustomer`, which is true if the customer is saved correctly, and false if not with an error being added to an errors collection which is maintained across the application (the collection of errors messages can then be shown/emailed to developers/logged etc). However, because the action is defined in within an `ICommand` instance, there is no way of informing the view if the customer has been successfully updated other than raising an error. So first question, how do I tell the view that its command is successful/not successful with information as to why?
2. Once this information is back at view level, I then want to Close the form only on success, by executing a `this.Close` presumably, otherwise show the information as to why the customer couldn't be saved. How should I handle this?

Comment: Looks complicated. Why would you not simply have three Click event handlers, where the one for Save would call a save method of the view model, the one for Save-and-close would do the same and subsequently (on success) call Close, and the third would simply call Close? MVVM does not mean you have to use commands.

Comment: Hi @Clemens, I'd happily do it that way using event handlers, and I do have 3 buttons as described, each referencing a different MVVM command. Part of what I'm trying to do is learn good methods, and am wondering if there is a good MVVM design pattern to handle CRUD operations and the responding appropriately in the UI. WPF/MVVM is designed to write database apps in a layered way, but if I use events, I'm ended up writing the same thing I would in winforms, except that I've refactored the EditMode down into the ViewModel. (1/2)

Comment: Is there a standard pattern for bubbling error messages up to the UI, or for a button to execute a XAML command, and then call code-behind depending on the success of the command? (2/2)

Comment: "*but if I use events, I'm ended up writing the same thing I would in winforms*" - not at all. In MVVM, the view knows the view model. The view may hence simply call a method of the view model. Having input event handlers in the view does not contradict MVVM.

Comment: @Clemens - my MVVM code isn't looking so different from my winforms code then. I've always had a data layer in separate classes (auto-generated from tables, with tweaks). My ViewModel equates to a standard set of methods that were in my form, that were pretty much agnostic to the form (using generic methods and the Tag property of controls to know which data came from/went to where). Other than that, I have events and public entry points, which is effectively the View. Perhaps I've been doing MVVM for years without knowing it.

Comment: Sure, you can of course implement MVVM in WinForms, or any other UI framework. It is the separation of the layers that makes MVVM, not details like data binding or commands.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens. I've learnt loads from this, in that WPF and the MS way of MVVM is really about ensuring correct encapsulation and layering of applications. Your comments much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> So first question, how do I tell the view that its command is successful/not successful with information as to why?

You could for example set a public property in the view model that the view binds to. Don't forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event to tell the view to refresh itself when the property is set to a new value.

> How should I handle this?

If the view model is responsible for creating and closing the windows, you should inject it with an interface that has a `Close()` method. This interface may be implemented by a view or a service of some kind. The important thing is that the view model knows only about the interface and not anything about a real view or window.

Comment: I'm guessing that (for encapsulation purposes) the ViewModel shouldn't be flagging up for the form to close (it doesn't know about the interface), rather that the customer was saved successfully, so some sort of infrastructure class where notifiers (i.e. the ViewModel) can flag up that certain events have occurred (e.g. customer has saved) and subscribers will get notified (the View) and then respond appropriately. I already have a data propogation class from my winforms days that will do this to keep subscribers elsewhere in the app in sync with the database content. Thanks.